# Laravel Query Multiple Collection Count

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a project with the classes Semester, Course, and Assignment.

I wanted to get only Semesters that had at least one Course associated with it, so I did this:

```
Semester::has('courses', '>', '0')->get();
```

Now, I want get Semesters that have at least one Course that has at least one Assignment associated with it.

In the Semester class, I have a `hasMany` relationship with Course, and in Course, I have a `hasMany` relationship with Assignments.  I also have a `belongsTo` for Assignment to Course and Course to Semester.

I have tried looking up closures, but none of the tutorials seem to relate to checking a collection of a collection.  How would I run this code?

## EDIT

After reading and testing more, I found that this code works:

```
Semester::whereHas('courses', function ($query) {
    $query->has('assignments', '>', '0')
})->get();
```

huuuk's answer is a different approach but equally valid and helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all define `hasManyThrough` [relation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) in `Semetster` class

```
public function assignments() 
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Course', 'App\Assignment');
}
```

then you can reach your goal like so

```
Semester::has('assignments', '>=', '1')->get();
```